# When and how does Linux to save VGA memroy to RAM? Is it in pm-suspend script? or in kernel after echo mem > /sys/power/state

Tags: linux, suspend, vga, acpi

Does anyone know when Linux save VGA memory to RAM? 
Is it in pm-suspend script before echo mem to /sys/power/state?
Is it in kernel after echo -n "mem" > /sys/power/state?
or both?

I have looked at the pm-suspend script, it uses vbetool to save the video state

> vbe vbestate save > /var/run/vbestate

Is this the right place to save the VGA memory to RAM?

But if I only run echo mem > /sys/power/state(skip pm-suspend script in userspace), the system still can wakeup with correct GUI.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done into the kernel space, mostly in the video graphic driver suspend/resume methods.
How it is done depends of the driver.(cf [Linux kernel documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/power/video.txt))